# Can't create folder using mkdir in perl, permission denied?

Tags: perl, iis, permissions, iis-7.5, mkdir

I'm trying to create a directory with a perl script after calling it via Ajax through a web interface. I'm using IIS7.5 to run my webserver.

The problem arises when I use either `mkdir($path)` or `system("mkdir", $path)`, with the errors being "Permission denied" or "Access is denied", respectively. I believe I've set up the permissions correctly to give read/write/execute permissions as well as special permissions to create files and folders to the script.

Please let me know also if this should should be posted elsewhere, thanks!

Comment: The user as which you run your script doesn't have permission to create the directory. Give it the necessary permissions or configure your web server to use a different user.

Comment: How do I either find out what user is running the script, or configure my web server to use a different user?

(Yes, I've tried searching online, but I seem to keep running into the same thing, which assumes that I know how to do either of the two things above. :( )

Comment: To find out the user running the script: `print scalar getpwuid($<), "\n"`.

Comment: I am having the same problem and it says the owner is www-data. This is on Google Cloud Compute. I don't have this problem on iPage. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I would think you could find the user running the script with "whoami".

Also, I'm not clear on what context the script is running in, nor where is the directory it is trying to create.  It might be necessary to add the "-p" option so that necessary parent directories are created.

No comment on the safety of this ... I assume that those checks are being made elsewhere.

Comment: Using `whoami`, I discovered that the user is `nt authority\iusr`. When I try to add this user to the permissions of the script, I'm getting "Name Not Found." Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that , the folder that you are planning to create this new folder in , must be owned by apache ( or any other web server software, you might be using ).

```
sudo chown apache *rootfolderfornewfolder*
```

I hope this helps